# Detect hover in overlaying element while allowing all pointer actions

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, css-animations

I am building an audio player in a SPA and have a main player widget that shows the currently playing track along with controls at the bottom of the page. The desired UI is to hide all controls but the play/pause button until the user hovers *near* the play/pause button. At this point the extra information, seek bar, volume controls etc. will be animated onto the screen.

[image]

*Excuse my shoddy drawing*

I should add that the controls are positioned fixed to the bottom of the screen.

Initially, I tried adding an extra fixed positioned div on top of everything (high z-index) and using that to trigger the hover event. Obviously, this doesn't allow for clicking the buttons below it so I tried `pointer-events: none` on the element but then no hover event is registered.

I then tried putting the hover region *underneath* the control elements and adding the hover trigger to both the hover region and the controls. This causes strange behavior when moving the cursor between the hover region and any controls (i.e. to click pause/play).

My next thought is to scrap the hover region HTML element and use a pure JS solution. I could register a `mousemove` event to the document body and detect when the cursor is within the hover region, triggering control animations. However, I am worried this might cause performance issues as seems a bit heavy.

I hope someone has some input/improvements on the things I have tried or comes up with something I haven't thought of!

**BTW:** I am using angular2 for the animation if that sparks some bright ideas to use that.

### Update 1

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwkd90vf/6/) showing the first two attempts. Change the z-index of `hover-region` to see the effect  of it being on top of the play button or below.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle with your code that doesn't work? As long as the hover region is as big as the toolbar you are showing, it should work without any strange behavior. Look at this. http://jsfiddle.net/bwkd90vf/

Comment: @ToddChaffee jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bwkd90vf/6/. The toolbar can be larger than the hover region

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a working version for you at http://jsfiddle.net/6wk69fvo/1/. You already did what I was going to suggest, which is to use `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave`.

But rather than just checking the hover area, you also need to check the toolbar area, and then just `OR` the two values together.

Also note that I put the play / pause button as a child of the hover area. If you don't want to do that, you'd need to create a third check for `mouseenter` or `mouseleave` for that div.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for this. I will put the play button outside of the over area but didn't specify that as wasn't really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the control's opacity make it visible/invisible. Here is a [simple example](http://jsbin.com/kihihu/edit?html,js,console,output) done in pure html/js to avoid the overhead of setting up an ng2 app, yet, I'm sure you can quickly adapt it to your code.

Comment: Thanks, but I should have mentioned that the extra controls are larger than the hover region so having as a child wouldn't work (as far as I'm aware). See the jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/bwkd90vf/6/

Comment: So you have a "hot zone" to show the controls, how do you hide them? What is the trigger?

Comment: Hiding them is  as simple as setting `display:none` or with the opacity as you suggested. The trigger is hovering in the "hotzone" near the play/pause button

Comment: I got this one, but when do you want to hide them? You show them on hover and hide them on.... ?

Comment: The element should be hidden once not hovered in the hot region. Please see the accepted answer